# Authenticate Attribute for MVC: ExecuteServiceStackFiltersAttribute: SessionFeature not present in time to set AuthSession?

Tags: servicestack

I'm trying to create a simple Credentials Auth using OrmLiteAuthRepository(Postgres) and Memcached as caching layer on Mono 3.2.x / Ubuntu 12.04 in an MVC Application - I am using ServiceStack libraries version 4.0x

I am using a custom session object, adapted from ServiceStack's SocialBootstrap example

**What works perfectly:**
Getting the session inside a controller action, such as:

```
 var currentSession = base.SessionAs<MyCustomUserSession>();
```

However, I don't want to check / validate the session and what may or may not be inside it in the action code, I would like to use an attribute, and this leads me to:

**What does not work:** Using the `Authenticate` attribute above the action name:
My problem (`null` `AuthSession`) shows up when trying to utilize the `[Authenticate]` attribute on an MVC action.

```
[Authenticate]
public ActionResult Index()
{
    return View();
}
```

I have managed to narrow it down to the fact that `ExecuteServiceStackFiltersAttribute` executes this code, but it appears the `AuthSession` has not yet been made available by the `SessionFeature` - so the `AuthSession` will always be null at this point:

```
var authAttrs = GetActionAndControllerAttributes<AuthenticateAttribute>(filterContext);
if (authAttrs.Count > 0 && ( ssController.AuthSession==null || !ssController.AuthSession.IsAuthenticated))
{
    filterContext.Result = ssController.AuthenticationErrorResult;
    return;
}
```

If, for example I override the `AuthenticationErrorResult` and try to throw an exception if I manually initialize the  session from the `SessionFeature`, it will throw the `"there is life in the session"` exception (of course, when I logged in with a valid user):

```
public override ActionResult AuthenticationErrorResult
{
    get
    {                
        if (AuthSession == null)
        {
            // the Authenticate filter is triggered by ExecuteServiceStackFilters attribute
            // which seems to always have AuthSession null
            var session = SessionFeature.GetOrCreateSession<MyCustomUserSession>(AuthService.Cache);
            if (session == null || (session != null && session.IsAuthenticated == false))
            {
                throw new Exception("Hmmm...dead as a dodo");
            }
            else
            {
                throw new Exception("there is life in the session:" + session.UserName);
            }
        }

        var returnUrl = HttpContext.Request.Url.PathAndQuery;
        return new RedirectResult(LoginRedirectUrl.Fmt(HttpUtility.UrlEncode(returnUrl)));

    }
}
```

Aside from creating my custom attributes / filters, is there a solution I should try (properties to set) with the incumbent ServiceStack codebase? If I'm missing something, please let me know.

My regards for a great project in any case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**My problem (null AuthSession) shows up when trying to utilize the [Authenticate] attribute on an MVC action.**
Are you getting an Exception or are you just getting redirected to the 'Login' page? If you are not getting an Exception and just be redirected because you're not authenticated, the below may work. Also, are you implementing your own Custom Authentication Provider? If so, could you post a sample of it?

I don't think you have it in your code samples but I think your MVC Controller code is probably something like...

```
public class SomeController : ServiceStackController
{
    [Authenticate]
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }
}
```

Can you try adding your custom `MyCustomUserSession` to the Type of the ServiceStackController making it...

```
public class SomeController : ServiceStackController<MyCustomUserSession>
{
    [Authenticate]
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your suggestion. The second one (strong-typing ServiceStackController with MyCustomUserSession) did the trick. Regards !